# Find Min Key by Value if Map contains key(SubString here ) for Map<String, Double>

Tags: java, hashmap, java-stream

I have a HashMap with Strings as keys and values. And I have a String. Now I want to do something like that:

Example

```
Map<String, Double> storeDistance = new HashMap<String, Double>();
map.put("10-ABCD-01", 15.75);
map.put("10-XYZ-05", 12.13);
map.put("10-ABCD-06", 11.06);
map.put("10-ABCD-04", 10.76);
map.put("10-XYZ-03", 07.62);
```

Now I Want to find Store ABCD with minimum distance out of all. Here in the case I want to get
Store Value as "10-ABCD-04" cause it has minimum distance out of all Keys with Substring ABCD.

I was trying something like below, but it was not working. So any Suggestion here.

```
storeDistance.keySet().stream()
                           .filter(key -> key.contains("ABCD")).map(storeDistance::get).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, Math::min));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `min(Comparator)` on the stream of your key set to get an optional key

```
String result = storeDistance.keySet().stream().filter(key -> key.contains("ABCD"))
       .min(Comparator.comparingDouble(storeDistance::get)).get();
```

Comment: Avoid map lookup, `String result = storeDistance.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().contains("ABCD")) .min(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()).map(Map.Entry::getKey) .get();`